# Adding “AllowUpload” to the landed code tab in the Bill and adjustment screen

Tags: visual-studio, acumatica

I'm trying to add the ability to upload order lines into landed cost on the bills and adjustment screen via excel or csv. I customized the screen and set AllowUpload to True. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXJlp.png) But i don't know how to use the [PXImport]. Can you guy show me step by step.Ex: what is the BQL and where 
to put it. Be specific. Thanks

Comment: My data view's name  is "landedCostTrans" and I need you guy's picture. All I know is write: [PXImport(typeof(APInvoice))]
public PXSelect<landedCostTran> MyDataView; in this empty extension graph: public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
  {
#region Event Handlers
[PXImport(typeof(APInvoice))]
public PXSelect<landedCostTran> MyDataView;
    #endregion
}I don't know how to  "created you add [PXImport(typeof(PrimaryDac)] right before the DataView declaration". I'm new to this. Thanks for helping me. Do i need to use visual studio to inject to source code ?

Answer (score 3):

First determine the name of the DataView bound to the grid. To do that you can hold Ctl-Alt and click on the header of the grid and select Customize. It will open the customization project editor in the Screen section. Click on the top most element of the tree view in the middle to select the grid. Lookup the DataMember property on the property pane on the right side, this is the name of the DataView. While in the project editor, expand the Mode section of the property pane and set AllowUpload property to True.

Now that you know the name of the DataView you need to decorate it with the PXImport attribute. Create a Graph Extension in the code section of the project editor for this screen if you haven't already. In the Graph Extension, for a new DataView that you have created you add [PXImport(typeof(PrimaryDac)] right before the DataView declaration like this:

```
[PXImport(typeof(APInvoice))]
public PXSelect<MyDAC> MyDataView;
```

For an existing DataView from the base class you can override it in the same way:

```
[PXImport(typeof(APInvoice))]
public PXSelect<DAC> BaseDataView;
```

The Primary DAC can be found in the class declaration of the base graph:

```
public class APInvoiceEntry : APDataEntryGraph<APInvoiceEntry, APInvoice>, PXImportAttribute.IPXPrepareItems
```

Reference: [Enabling Upload from Excel for the Grid](http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/12/enabling-upload-from-excel-for-grid.html)

Comment: You also need AllowUpload in the page file in PXGrid Mode. Ex: <Mode AllowUpload="True"/>

Comment: Yes of course, I thought question seemed to be oriented toward PXImport since OP mentioned having already set AllowUpload. It's a good idea to add complete steps so I edited my answer to add that.

Comment: ah yes sorry i missed that. +1 I think you need the typeof(PrimaryDac) as a parameter to PXImport? For example in INSiteMaint "[PXImport(typeof(INSite))]" .For reference to anyone the http://asiablog.acumatica.com/ site listed in the answer is a very resourceful site for Acumatica development. Welcome to the Acumatica community on stackoverflow TrungDo

Comment: When the Primary DAC is the same as the DAC of the DataView I believe it is optional. I'm not sure for other cases, maybe using the Primary DAC is required. I've edited my answer to use the primary DAC parameter of PXImport attribute.

Comment: I have always needed to include it but i usually perform it on a grid that is not the primary so I cannot say for sure. Was just worth pointing out. Still a good answer.

Comment: My data view's name  is "landedCostTrans" and I need you guy's picture. All I know is write: [PXImport(typeof(APInvoice))]
public PXSelect<landedCostTran> MyDataView; in this empty extension graph: public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
  {
#region Event Handlers
[PXImport(typeof(APInvoice))]
public PXSelect<landedCostTran> MyDataView;
    #endregion
}I don't know how to  "created you add [PXImport(typeof(PrimaryDac)] right before the DataView declaration". I'm new to this. Thanks for helping me. Do i need to use visual studio to inject to source code ?

Comment: You say your Data view name is "LandedCostTrans" but you have "[PXImport(typeof(APInvoice))] public PXSelect<landedCostTran> MyDataView" which says your data view name is "MyDataView". Your Dac Name goes inside the PXSelect with your where statement to get the LandedCostTrans records related to your APInvoice. What errors or issues are you currently having? still not showing?

Comment: I try to add this to the AP301000 Screen, in the Landed Costs tab which only appear when you choose the vendor having Landed Cost Vendor Properties checked. Can you help me with the where statement: This is what i have so far: PXSelect<LandedCostTran, Where<LandedCostTran.DocType, Equal<Current<APInvoice.DocType>>, 
               And<LandedCostTran.RefNbr, Equal<Current<APInvoice.RefNbr>>>>,OrderBy<Asc<LandedCostTran.DocType, Asc<LandedCostTran.RefNbr>>>> LandedCostTrans; and the error is: 'DocType'&'RefNbr' does not exist in the type 'PX.Objects.PO.LandedCostTran'&'PX.Objects.AP.APInvoice'

Comment: In BQL you use first letter lower case to reference the DAC fields: LandedCostTran.docType, LandedCostTran.refNbr

Comment: Thanks but still not working !. The same error. I think I wrong about relationship and column

Comment: @Brendan asiablog.acumatica.com is such a goldmine for this kind of stuff. Craps all over the in-built documentation. Unfortunately it doesn't make the framwork any better. I'm trying to override the RowImported function in SOOrderEntry and it's impossible because the idiots haven't declared the method virtual!!

Comment: unfortunately there is plenty of places that can be improved to allow customization to function - Ex non private calls that can be virtual. Maybe overriding PrepareImportRow? i haven't extended the import logic before so not sure but the regular events still run for the imports so should be able to use those as needed. You can look at the graph IsImport flag too which might be true during import.