# Using Load Records from File on Custom Table

Tags: acumatica

I want to set up the Load Records from File button on a custom table grid that I added to the ProjectEntry_Extension BLC. I have the view set up with PXImport:

```
[PXImport(typeof(CFPMItemReq))]
public PXSelect<CFPMItemReq, Where<CFPMItemReq.projectID, 
   Equal<Current<PMProject.contractID>>>> ItemReqs;
```

I set the grid Mode -> Allow Update = true. I added IItemPlanMaster to the DAC of CFPMItemReq:

```
[Serializable]
public class CFPMItemReq : IBqlTable, IItemPlanMaster
{
    ....
}
```

However, when I go to upload the file, nothing happens. The button opens the file browser, I select the file, click upload, and the window just closes and nothing happens. I double checked and the excel file is formatted properly with the IDs of the columns in the first row. I'm not sure what I'm missing to get this working.

Comment: is CFPMItemReq your primary view DAC type for that graph? If not change it the primary view. For example on sales order import of sales lines the PXImport tyep of is not soline, its SOOrder as SOOrder is the primary view dac

Comment: I forgot to mention that the graph is an extension of an Acumatica base graph. The specific graph extension is for ProjectEntry. I will add that detail to the original post.

Comment: you need to use the primary DAC in your PXImport and should work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `PXImport` on a view in your extension which is based on `ProjectEntry`, you will need to use the primary DAC of that graph which should be `PMProject` like this...

```
[PXImport(typeof(PMProject))]
public PXSelect<CFPMItemReq, Where<CFPMItemReq.projectID, 
   Equal<Current<PMProject.contractID>>>> ItemReqs;
```

Here are similar questions:

[Nothing happen after click upload excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048040/nothing-happen-after-click-upload-excel/45059835#45059835)

[Adding “AllowUpload” to the landed code tab in the Bill and adjustment screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175705/adding-allowupload-to-the-landed-code-tab-in-the-bill-and-adjustment-screen/44181563#44181563)

Comment: Ohhhh, like an Action Button?

Comment: It worked, but now when I'm on the custom graph and I go to do anything like switch the record, I get the error message "The method or operation is not implemented." Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: seems like something is calling throw new NotImplementedException? could be a call in Acumatica. what does the trace window who in Acumatica (stack trace)? i see a few calls in PMAllocator

Comment: When I try to import, I get this error: "Error: An error occurred during processing of the field SiteID : The method or operation is not implemented.." I don't have a SiteID that I'm trying to import.

Comment: Alright, looks like I found the error. It is in the CFPMItemReq file. I should have looked more into the stack trace as it gave the exact location. Thanks for the help Brendan!